# Programmatically change the width of the Button in android

Tags: android

How to change the `width` of a `Button` programmatically. I am able to change the `height` but the width does not change. Following is my code snippet

```
private void createButton(final String label)
{

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(label);


    button.setWidth(10);
    button.setHeight(100);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {


        }
    });
    mMenuContainer.addView(button, mMenuItemLayoutParamters);


}
```

But the `width` of the `Button` occupies the `width` of the screen.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));`

Should have work for you.

There is one Awesome Example online for this : [check this](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/resize-button-programmatically-using.html)

---

you should apply `LayoutParams` of the `ViewGroup` that contains your `View`. That is, if your button is inside `RelativeLayout`, you should use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: important to note: you should apply `LayoutParams` of the `ViewGroup` that contains your `View`. That is, if your button is inside `RelativeLayout`, you should use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: You should multiply your size values by the display scale, because the constructor takes pixels, not dp.
Like so:
widthInPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * widthInDp;

Comment: The recommendation about using the correct ViewGroup must be followed. If you use an incorrect VG, the app will crash and logcat will have zero information on the reason

Comment: I wonder why setWIdth() and setHeight() are even offered for buttons and textviews when they don't appear to work in practice, including for myself. I see dozens of 'Question: setWIdth() doesn't work, Answer: use LayoutParams' on this site.

Comment: For Kotlin programmers, it should work like this: `button.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100)`

Answer (score 48):

you can do it this way.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 100;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

but make sure you do this, after adding your button to a parent. and `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` is used when parent is a `LinearLayout` and when parent is `RelativeLayout` use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Setting a width can set "px" value or "dp" and how can we change it into dp if we set dp value on XML at the first beginner value, for example width="50dp" ?

Answer (score 4):

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) yourButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = 150;
yourButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

the "ConstraintLayout" can change up to your layout and set size by "layoutParams.width". This case it's work for me!

Answer (score 2):

can do this

```
    int width= (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_width);
    int heigth= (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_heigth);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, heigth);
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved by using this:

```
//ImageButton creation
final ImageButton server_icon_button=new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
//setting background image in drawable
server_icon_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bonsai);
//After adding ImageButton to the parent i done this
server_icon_button.getLayoutParams().height=180;
server_icon_button.getLayoutParams().width=100;
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using AppCompatImageButton (and AppCompat).
It turns out that if I keep density adjusted images in the various drawable
folders: drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc.. then the button won't scale.
Instead I had to *put a single drawable for each button in drawable-nodpi*.
Make sure the drawable-nodpi button image is of the *largest* size you need. Android will not scale the button size up; however, it can scale the size down. I created a button in XML like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:meter="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button"
        android:focusable="true">
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="MyAppTheme">
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/buttonColorPressed</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
</style>

<!-- v21/styles.xml -->
<style name="TargetButton" parent="MyAppTheme">
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/buttonColorPressed</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/button_elevation</item>
</style>

<!-- drawable/button_selector.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>
</selector>

<!-- drawable/button.xml -->
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_button"
      android:gravity="center" />

<!-- drawable/button_pressed.xml -->
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_button_pressed"
      android:gravity="center" />
```

Next, in onCreate when you retrieve the button, call **adjustButtonSize** (which i put in my base class):

```
    mButton = (AppCompatImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    adjustButtonSize(mButton);

public void adjustButtonSize(AppCompatImageButton button) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height / 10;         // 10%
    params.width = ((width * 20) / 100); // 20%
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using only `mMenuContainer.addView(button);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this kotlin code.

This is great when you want to give the size of another view to some other view.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        equalToButton.post(Runnable { zeroButton.height = equalToButton.height })
    }
}
```