# I have a problem in GridLayout I want to display 49 buttons inside but it does not work Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gridlayout

I have a problem in GridLayout. I want to display 49 buttons inside but it does not work 7 column and 7 row

XML :

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/MYG"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="7"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="7">
</GridLayout>
```

Code Java (Android Studio).

```
Button[] myButton=new Button[49];
for(i=0;i<49;i++) {
    myButton[i] = new Button(this);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    myButton[i].setText(String.valueOf(i));
    myButton[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonvid);
    colon.addView(myButton[i]);
}
```

The last two are hidden in each row.

[image: The result : The last two are hidden in each row]

Comment: Share your item view xml code for more understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue in your code! Only thing is that 2 of your columns are not visible on the screen due to small screen size.

**Possible Solution:**
your can either keep the size of each box smaller so that all boxes can be shown or some other way to keep them on available screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment but How keep the size of each box smaller !

Comment: you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293932/programmatically-change-the-width-of-the-button-in-android/11294075

Comment: @vinom I am glad to know that